# gzip all files without deleting them

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, gzip

I need to gzip all files in a dir separately including all files in sub-directories without deleting the originals afterwards.
So let's say I have index.html, I want to have at the end index.html.gzip AND index.html.

I am able to gzip all files in my dir via

```
gzip -r .
```

But I want to keep the original files also.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
find . -type f | \
while read -r x
do
  gzip -c "$x" > "$x.gz"
done
```

The `-c` pushes the result to stdout and keeps the original alone. The disadvantage is, that you need to find the files yourself. For more sophisticated traversing, you can use `find(1)`, however, like above: `.` searches starting from the current directory, and `-type f` returns the name of every regular file.

Comment: Why `*.*` in `ls`?

Comment: @pooh: `*.*` matches all regularly named files, and usually no directories. Of course, it only works in most cases and usually not if you need it. Then use the `find` command.

Comment: @Boldewyn: the question was to gzip all files in a dir. `ls *.*` won't pick files like **TODO**.

Comment: `ls` isn't needed *at all*: `for x in *`. However, using `find` should be `find . -type f | while read -r x`.

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks for the `-r` switch on `read`.

Comment: Don't need the continuation character: the pipe can be followed by a newline

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type f -not \( -name '*.gz' -or -name '*[~#]' \) -exec sh -c 'gzip -c "{}" > "{}.gz"' \;
```

You could easily switch it around to include what you want to compress ( `-name '*.txt -or -name '*.html` etc.) instead of like now, excluding some files (already compressed, backup and temporary files).

Handles spaces in the filename just fine too.

Change `gzip` to  `echo gzip` for testing. Or skip the -exec part all together.

**Edit:** Oh, I forgot to mention that this doesn't check if `<target>.gz` already exists. This may or may not be a problem.

**Edit2:** Ok, here we go with something that checks for existing file. If that may be wanted. Pardon the oneliney-ness.

```
while read file; do if [ ! -f "$file.gz" ]; then echo "Compressing $file"; gzip -c "$file" > "$file.gz"; else echo "Not overwriting $file.gz";  fi  done < <(find . -type f -not \( -name '*.gz' -or -name '*[~#]' \))
```

My `find`-foo is maybe not what it could be, it may very well be possible to skip directly in find.

Comment: just read that -name should come before -type to avoid calling stat on every file.

Comment: @Ben Makes sense, good input! For large trees it might be noticeable.

Answer (score 3):

**gzip `-k` option**

gzip 1.6 (June 2013) added the `-k, --keep` option, so now you can:

```
gzip -kr .
```

and it won't delete your original files.

Found at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46786/how-to-tell-gzip-to-keep-original-file

Answer (score 2):

Just add the -c option, I think this should work

Comment: This probably only works when gzipping a single file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
gzip -rc `ls` > archive.gz
```

Tested on Debian (gzip 1.3.12-6)

Comment: That creates one archive. The OP wants separate archives. `ls` is unnecessary, use `*`.